# I just tried to change my fluorescent bulbs in garage and when I screwed one in it started arcing

Tags: lighting, fluorescent

I have this fluorescent light fixture in my garage that holds two 4-ft lights.
I got one put in and it lit up on both ends but when I try to plug the other one in it started sparking.
What could do this and why? This has been up for many years.

Comment: ...turn the switch off. Change the bulbs. Turn the switch on.

Comment: It seems like the problem is you are trying to change the lights while they are turned on.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big deal. A fluorescent is an "arc discharge light" which means there is a lightning-like electric arc going down the tube.   Getting that arc started requires extra-high voltage, so the ballast is sending higher voltage than normal to get that arc started.  Once the arc is struck, the ballast automatically lowers voltage to sustain levels.

So yeah, when you install the tube *with the power on*, that arcing is to be expected, and can be ignored.

Don't handle the tube by the ends if you're going to install tubes with the power on :)

The newest fluorescent tubes are 90 CRI, which means better quality light than most LEDs.  As such I'm staying with real fluorescent.

Comment: Care to join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) to explain the CRI point?

Comment: @FreeMan CRI is simply light quality, how color-true things will look to the eye.  Sunlight is 100 (%) CRI, incandescent is about 100.  LEDs tend to be fairly notchy light, and that can degrade CRI.